# Use Docker and Nginx to deploy my Application with 2 Vue Frontends and one Spring Backend with SSL - keep getting SSL errors

Tags: firebase, docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

### Context

I have had my application running with a global Nginx as a reverse proxy on my private server without issues. However, for my project I need to deploy it on the servers of my university where I'll need to move all that into my Containers, but I cannot make it work.

### General Project Setup

Short introduction to the setup: I have my frontend-ui, which is a simple PWA I built with vue that also uses Firebase Messaging for notifications. Notification tokens are stored via my notification manager - a spring application - in a database and it also performs all database queries such as removing the tokens upon deletion etc. My third ui ist the notification-ui that provides a simple (vue) frontend to send out notifications with firebase, for that it also interacts with the database to retrieve the tokens. All projects are located in one folder with a docker-compose.
I need both of my Frontends to serve https.

### Nginx / Docker Setup

#### frontend-ui

My frontend-ui has the following Nginx configuration and the certificates are in the folder certificates:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name SERVERNAME;
  # Redirect all traffic to SSL
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED";

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  server_name SERVERNAME;

  ## Access and error logs.
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

  ## Server certificate and key.
  ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:42372;
  }
}
```

and this Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
#COPY certificates/nginx.cert /etc/ssl/
#COPY certificates/nginx.key /etc/ssl/

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

COPY certificates/nginx.cert /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY certificates/nginx.key /etc/nginx/ssl/

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#### notification-ui

My notification-ui has the following Nginx configuration and the certificates are in the folder certificates:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name SERVERNAME;
  # Redirect all traffic to SSL
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED";

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  server_name SERVERNAME;

  ## Access and error logs.
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

  ## Server certificate and key.
  ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:42372;
  }
}
```

and this Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
#COPY certificates/nginx.cert /etc/ssl/
#COPY certificates/nginx.key /etc/ssl/

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

COPY certificates/nginx.cert /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY certificates/nginx.key /etc/nginx/ssl/

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#### Notification-backend

My backend doesn't have an Nginx config, as it does not need it per se. The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
### BUILDER
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim as builder

RUN mkdir -p /build
WORKDIR /build
COPY pom.xml /build

#Download dependencies
#RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins

#copy src-code
COPY src /build/src

#Build application
RUN mvn clean install

### RUNTIME

FROM openjdk:11-slim as runtime
ENV APP_HOME /

#Create folders for config and logging
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/config
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/log

VOLUME $APP_HOME/log
VOLUME $APP_HOME/config

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
#Copy jar from builder
COPY --from=builder /build/target/*.jar notificationmanager.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","notificationmanager.jar", "de.hsa.frontend.notificationmanager.NotificationmanagerApplication"]
```

### Deployment

I deploy the network using a docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
    backend:
        image: notificationmanager-be:1
        build:
            context: ./notificationmanager
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "42372:8085"
        networks:
            - notificationmanager
        restart: on-failure:5
    notification-ui:
        image: notificationmanager-ui:1
        build:
            context: ./notificationmanager-ui
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "42373:80"
            - "42376:443"
        networks:
            - notificationmanager
    db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "42374:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=USERNAME
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
            - POSTGRES_DB=DATABASE
        volumes:
            - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        restart: on-failure:5
    frontend-ui:
        image: frontend-ui:1
        build:
            context: ./frontend-ui
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "42375:80"
            - "42377:443"
        networks:
            - notificationmanager
networks:
    notificationmanager:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    data:
        driver: local
```

The mapping of port 443 I added as a last idea as to why it might not work so I can also take it out again. I cannot really see much of a difference from online-Tutorials I have viewed, but I still get a SSL-error (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) when trying to open the webpages, the Dev-Tools don't show any errors, the logs from the frontend-ui look like this (others are similar):

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration


/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/


/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh


10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version


/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh


/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up


2021/03/29 11:55:04 [warn] 1#1: the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:23


nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:23


10.144.43.100 - - [29/Mar/2021:11:55:53 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xB1\xC7" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"


10.144.43.100 - - [29/Mar/2021:11:55:53 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03:X\xFB\x83\xAD\x18\x13n^\xF4\x06:\xED\x93~;\xB2%j\xD0\xAC\xDC\xFB#W\xCB)b\x16r\xC9\xCE \xFE\x1Fu\xA3Y;\xB2\xC0\xFB\x11 \x02\xDE\x91=$U" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"


10.144.43.100 - - [29/Mar/2021:11:55:54 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03Bp\x91\xA8\xC6h)\x81\xA41\x12\xAAl\xF4\xD1q\xA8\xEA\xC6{\xC4\x0B\x83\xA9\xE1\xFCJ@1#\x1F\xB9 ?\xCFV\xA7\x0Fvx\x1C\xF5\xF5\xA4\x0B\xAF\xA2Z>\xB4\xCA\xC4!i;F6\xC0\x1F\xB5H\x94\xC4\xBC\x19\x00\x22::\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"


10.144.43.100 - - [29/Mar/2021:11:55:54 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\x9D#Ju;j24\xC0\xF6\xEA\xDC\xBF\xFA\x0E;\xBDJ\x030\xD4\xF6\xE8V\x88I\xB8/'\xA6Vj \xA1B\x17\x5C$" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

I did a bit of renaming to improve the readability and tried to remove all my (failed) attempts on possible issues so I apologize if I failed that somewhere. I had to remove some values (like login data for the database) so I just wrote placeholders there, of course the files are filled completely.
Can anyone point me to my error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are exposing the ports in the dockerfiles.  I think you'll want to add this to your nginx dockerfiles

```
EXPOSE 80 443
```

And this to your java dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 8085
```

Once you expose those ports, you'll probably run into a problem with the reverse proxy.  Each container has it's own `localhost`, so in your nginx configs, this line won't work.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:42372;
```

You can access the backend container "directly" without going through the docker host.  Try changing that line to

```
proxy_pass http://backend:8085;
```

Similarly, I suspect you're trying to connect to your db using `localhost:42374`.  You'll probably need to change that to `db:5432`.

Comment: This helped soo much! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to hear that.  Did it answer your question completely or do you need additional information?  If it answered it completely please consider accepting it.